# Memory Usage of Each Application Pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, application-pool

I Use IIS 7.5 and I have Some ASP.NET sites and Some Web Services in different Application pools. In current days the Memory of server is in high usage, So how I know each application pool used memory? Is there any way? any suggestion?

Answer (score 65):

- Go to IIS Manager
- Click on the name of your server in the Connections pane
- Under the IIS section in the Features View, double-click the `Worker Processes` icon

Here you can see both the private bytes and virtual bytes usage of each running application pool.

[image: IIS snapshot]

More information can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771273(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: "Under IIS" threw me off. ngm means: In the main features section of the IIS manager window. You don't select a site or an app domain, but the top-level server node then on the right there will be heaps of features you can select from.

Answer (score 23):

Each app pool will be in its own w3wp.exe process.

Open task manager, then go to Details tab.  Right-click on the columns, select "Select columns".  (On some versions of Windows it is in them menu: View -> Select Columns).  Make sure "Command line" is selected.

Then sort by name, and look at your w3wp.exe instances, and compare memory usage.  You can tell which app pool each one uses because the name will show up in the command line.

Comment: We have only one instance of w3wp.exe

Comment: Then you only have one active app pool going.  Each app pool will have its own w3wp process.

Comment: Thats not correct, each application in site can have own App Pool but each site have own w3wp process

Comment: Each App Pool definitely has its own process (but technically speaking it can have more than one process).  A site has to belong to an App Pool, but many sites can share the same App Pool:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.01.servingtheweb.aspx.  If you do the trick in my answer, you'll see which App Pool your w3wp.exe belongs to.  If you have many sites, make sure they run in different app pools, then you can see memory usage for each.  You may also be confusing App Pools with App Domains - if so do a search on these terms.

Comment: Yes, But I can't make more sites, I need Memory Usage per App pool in one site!

Comment: An AppPool is an AppDomain of which multiple can run in a single process. Unless you have turned on AppPool per Process, they will all run in a single Process by default.